# Visual Studio 2015: Cannot add DLL reference when importing existing project

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

When I import an existing project, I can't add a reference to a DLL that is in the same solution.

I click "Add Reference", click the DLL check box, then click ok and when I go back, it is unchecked again...

But even when I check the Debug folder, it's there. When I run the project with errors, it's there (the program actual works). However, Visual Studio keeps saying my project has errors because it can't see the DLL and says it doesn't exist when I manually type in the "using" statement. If I click on "References" I see it, but it has a warning symbol and if I double-click on it I get an error:

"This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built. Please ensure that the project is available and built."

Comment: If the project is in your solution add reference on it not on dll.

Comment: the warning symbol probably indicates that it isn't there.  Though, this could be a project/solution .net framework targeting version issue.. Ensure the .net version of the dll is 'specific' to the version you're running; or rather, the version that you intend to load. in the project **reference** folder

Comment: additionally, you should ensure the dll is set to **Compile** on the build action. Also, I don't usually put my dll files in my bin directory, as that's the output folder. you don't actually need your reference assembly to be in your project, you just need to ensure it is compiled and 'Copied' to the Output Directory if it isn't in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) of the targetted machine.

Comment: You are doing something wrong but the description doesn't help much.  Explain how this project could be built before you imported it without that DLL.  And try removing the reference and adding it back.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thank you! The error was from it using a different version of the .NET framework.